# SQL: Sum of tables with uneven rows

Tags: sql

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT
payment.receipt AS or_no,
payment.payment_dt,
payment.vno,
concat(p.family_name, ', ', p.given_name, ' ', p.middle_name, COALESCE(', ' || p.suffix, '')) AS name,
$$English's Special$$ AS department,
SUM(payment.amount) AS income,
SUM(discount.amount) AS discount,
0 AS other_discount,
0 AS tax
FROM payment_tbl payment
LEFT JOIN person p ON payment.person_id = p.id
INNER JOIN discount_tbl discount on payment.vno = discount.vno 
GROUP BY or_no, name, payment_dt, payment.vno, payment.amount

UNION ALL 

...


SELECT * FROM payment_tbl:
receipt | amount | vno
1       | 5000   | V2016197

SELECT * FROM discount_tbl;
id | vno       | gross | amount (20% discount)
1  | V2016197  | 0     | 0
2  | V2016197  | 0     | 0
3  | V2016197  | 3000  | 600
```

If I do the `select * from payment_tbl inner join discount_tbl`, the result would be 3 rows, thus the `SUM(payment.amount)` would be 15000 instead of 5000.

How can I join the two tables?

Comment: Your logic/problem are not clear to me.  Even if you do join the two tables, only one record has non zero values for the `gross`.  Then what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion ? Use a correlated query to sum the amount from `discount_tbl` , then it won't produce duplicate records:

```
SELECT
payment.receipt AS or_no,
payment.payment_dt,
payment.vno,
concat(p.family_name, ', ', p.given_name, ' ', .middle_name, COALESCE(', ' || p.suffix, '')) AS name,
$$English's Special$$ AS department,
SUM(payment.amount) AS income,
(SELECT SUM(d.amount) FROM discount_tbl d
 WHERE d.vno = payment.vno) as discount ,
0 AS other_discount,
0 AS tax
FROM payment_tbl payment
LEFT JOIN person p ON payment.person_id = p.id
GROUP BY or_no, name, payment_dt, payment.vno, payment.amount
```

Btw, in the `CONCAT()` you are missing the alias in `.middle_name` , typo?

Comment: thank you, this worked well. i was focused on making the SUM(payment.amount) as the sub-select and cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select sum(amount) from payment_tbl a where a.vno = b.vno) as amount 
from discount_tbl b
```

Try this query. Instead of join use a subquery to get amount.

Answer (score 0):

You should `SUM` your discounts on the `discount_tbl` table and use the produced table in the `JOIN`

```
.
.
SUM(payment.amount) AS income,
discount.amount AS discount,
0 AS other_discount,
0 AS tax
FROM payment_tbl payment
LEFT JOIN person p ON payment.person_id = p.id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT vno,SUM(amount) amount FROM discount_tbl GROUP BY vno ) discount 
on payment.vno = discount.vno 
.
.
```